# onkeyup way too slow

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, onkeyup

http://jsbin.com/ezecun/edit#javascript,html

I have to write it this way because it is dynamicly made, actual code listed below. I simplified it a bit in the jsbin. Basically it takes so long to update the array with the value of the box it is unusable.

Thanks for taking a look.

CODE:
php

```
echo "<label style='float:left'>Comments: </label> <textarea onKeyUp=\"editItemInCart(this.value,'comments',".$itemNum.")\" onChange=\"editItemInCart(this.value,'comments',".$itemNum.")\" >".$cart['comments']."</textarea><br />";
```

javascript

```
function editItemInCart(newValue,fieldName,itemNum) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "editItem.html",
        data: "newvalue=" + newValue + "&fieldname=" + fieldName + "&itemNum=" + itemNum,
    })
    //alert(newValue + fieldName + itemNum);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do?

Comment: It's not the keyup event that's slow, but the script has to wait for the server to respond to the AJAX query. Have you measured how long it takes for the editItem.html to process the query?

Comment: I want it update an array with new values based on the two events there. 

The page is less than a second, no problem. I think adding a delay where it waits for inactivity and then updates would be better, so its not constantly firing.

Comment: A full round-trip HTTP request is going to take (say) 1 second. I can hammer out at least 5 or 6 characters without even trying in that same time period. That means your earlier ajax requests are going to be busy processing data that is now completely stale, as they're at least 5 or 6 characters out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really want to post on each typed key or when the user finishes typing? Most people can type a whole word before one letter is processed. You need a count. Something like this:

```
var count = 0;
function doEditItemInCart(newValue,fieldName,itemNum)
{
    count++;
    setTimeout("editItemInCart('"+newValue+"','"+fieldName+"',"+itemNum+","+count+")",200);
}
function editItemInCart(newValue,fieldName,itemNum,cnt) {
if (count == cnt) {
        count = 0;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "editItem.html",
            data: "newvalue=" + newValue + "&fieldname=" + fieldName + "&itemNum=" + itemNum,
        })
        //alert(newValue + fieldName + itemNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay this works much better, its still a delay, just not as bad. I think I need to put a "saved" div somewhere so the customer knows. Marked answered.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you want to [debounce](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) the `keyup` event. I recommend Ben Alman's [jQuery throttle / debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

```
var itemNum = $('#item_num_id').val();
$('#textarea_id').keyup($.debounce(250, editItemInCart(this.value,'comments', itemNum)));
```

The above code eliminates the inline event handlers, giving you nice separation between markup and code.

Comment: I don't really want to add another library, even a small one. The answer I marked uses code I already have. Thanks though!